# File sync fails after first table

Tags: c#, file, azure, android-asynctask, azure-blob-storage

I have trying to add file sync to my adaptation to Field Engineer using Xamarin. I have got it to do the first table Jobs. but New_Contact table started but get the following errors.

Client code

```
namespace FieldStaff
{
public class New_ContactService
{

public async Task<IEnumerable<New_Contact>> ReadContacts(string search)
    {
        return await JobService.contactTable.ToEnumerableAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<New_Contact>> ReadContact(string search)
    {
        return await JobService.contactTable.Where(item => item.Contact_ID == search).ToEnumerableAsync();
    }

    public async Task PostNew_Contact(New_Contact contact)
    {
        try
        {
            await JobService.contactTable.InsertAsync(contact);

            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                await this.SyncAsync();

            //return verifyGIUD("Tables", new {id = current.Id}, current);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //return ex.Message;
        }

    }

    public async Task UpdateContactAsync(New_Contact contact)
    {
        await JobService.contactTable.UpdateAsync(contact);

        // trigger an event so that the job list is refreshed
        //await MobileService.EventManager.PublishAsync(new MobileServiceEvent("JobChanged"));
    }

    public async Task SyncAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await JobService.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            await JobService.contactTable.PullAsync(null, JobService.contactTable.CreateQuery());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
    public async Task CompleteContactAsync(New_Contact contact)
    {
        await UpdateContactAsync(contact);

        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            await this.SyncAsync();
    }
}
```

}

Server Code

```
namespace FieldEngineer.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class New_ContactStorageController : StorageController<New_Contact>
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("tables/New_Contact/{id}/StorageToken")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostStorageTokenRequest(string id, StorageTokenRequest value)
    {
        StorageToken token = await GetStorageTokenAsync(id, value);

        return Request.CreateResponse(token);
    }

    // Get the files associated with this record
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("tables/New_Contact/{id}/MobileServiceFiles")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFiles(string id)
    {
        IEnumerable<MobileServiceFile> files = await GetRecordFilesAsync(id);

        return Request.CreateResponse(files);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("tables/New_Contact/{id}/MobileServiceFiles/{name}")]
    public Task Delete(string id, string name)
    {
        return base.DeleteFileAsync(id, name);
    }
}
```

}

```
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET http://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Information: 0 : Redirecting: https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 1048.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated gstephens@ducks.org successfully using 'Session Cookie' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/, Message='https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Home', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Controllers.HomeController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Controllers.HomeController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'Index()'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Action returned 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Content.StaticHtmlActionResult'', Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=HomeController.ExecuteAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=200 (OK), Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/, Message='Content-type='text/html; charset=utf-8', content-length=141290'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=HomeController.Dispose
The thread 0x2d60 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1584 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x23d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d88 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1a38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xf4c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2ccc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1274 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2d7c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x24f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Information: 0 : Redirecting: https://login.windows.net/002aea92-0ce0-476d-9cb6-fd35308d3db3/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=2f1d7cff-4389-4d2d-b87e-ba896c92d766&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&state=%23&nonce=7d0e6afc15fd441db0aa29ccb3344914_20161006225954
The thread 0x2a6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: POST https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'uy98iHKp8S2LsbP8vO9g9SRnKAo913MlJVnCh5yF4UI', Issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/002aea92-0ce0-476d-9cb6-fd35308d3db3/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Information: 0 : Login completed for 'gstephens@ducks.org'. Provider: 'aad'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Writing 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 1068.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Information: 0 : Redirecting: https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done#token=%7B%22authenticationToken%22%3A%22eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzaWQ6ZWQ3MDQ0ZjA3ZTJhYWQ3YjM4NDRlMzBhOGY0Mzk2NzciLCJpZHAiOiJhYWQiLCJ2ZXIiOiI0IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kdWdpc2ZpZWxkc3RhZmYuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kdWdpc2ZpZWxkc3RhZmYuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIiwiZXhwIjoxNDc1Nzk4MTE5LCJuYmYiOjE0NzU3OTQ1MjB9.7VO3amgiGS8Bvv4eqvX_Mg_DglUDYfsFDTFvwLTSDtE%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22userId%22%3A%22sid%3Aed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677%22%7D%7D
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Information: 0 : Sending response: 200.0 OK
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/favicon.ico
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 1068.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated gstephens@ducks.org successfully using 'Session Cookie' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/favicon.ico, Message='https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/favicon.ico'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=404 (NotFound), Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/favicon.ico, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1060714226/ROOT-3-131202678307569760): Loaded 'D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Information: 0 : Sending response: 200.0 OK
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job?$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job?$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true, Message='https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job?$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Job', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='FieldEngineer.Controllers.JobController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='FieldEngineer.Controllers.JobController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'GetAllJobs(String search)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'search' bound to the value ''', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: search=', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableControllerConfigAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1060714226/ROOT-3-131202678307569760): Loaded 'D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1060714226/ROOT-3-131202678307569760): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-FieldEngineer'. 
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Action returned 'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Employee] AS [Employee], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Monitor_Date] AS [Monitor_Date], 
    [Extent1].[Region] AS [Region], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Easement] AS [Easement], 
    [Extent1].[Subdivision] AS [Subdivision], 
    [Extent1].[Subdivision_Num] AS [Subdivision_Num], 
    [Extent1].[GPSLat] AS [GPSLat], 
    [Extent1].[GPSLong] AS [GPSLong], 
    [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Extent1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Extent1].[Zip_Code] AS [Zip_Code], 
    [Extent1].[Easement_Name] AS [Easement_Name], 
    [Extent1].[Acres] AS [Acres], 
    [Extent1].[Location] AS [Location], 
    [Extent1].[Conservation] AS [Conservation], 
    [Extent1].[Amendment] AS [Amendment], 
    [Extent1].[Sale_Date] AS [Sale_Date], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
    [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
    [Extent1].[Contact] AS [Contact]
    FROM [dbo].[Jobs] AS [Extent1]'', Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableControllerConfigAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JobController.ExecuteAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=200 (OK), Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job?$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true&$select=Id,Employee,Status,Monitor_Date,Region,Project_ID,Easement,Subdivision,Subdivision_Num,GPSLat,GPSLong,City,State,Zip_Code,Easement_Name,Acres,Location,Conservation,Amendment,Sale_Date,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,Version,Deleted,Contact, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JobController.Dispose
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job?$skip=50&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job?$skip=50&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true, Message='https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job?$skip=50&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Job', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='FieldEngineer.Controllers.JobController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='FieldEngineer.Controllers.JobController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/00b05662-9643-4e36-bbeb-7b1961ca3ee7/MobileServiceFiles
Message='Selected action 'GetAllJobs(String search)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'search' bound to the value ''', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: search=', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/00b05662-9643-4e36-bbeb-7b1961ca3ee7/MobileServiceFiles, Message='https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/00b05662-9643-4e36-bbeb-7b1961ca3ee7/MobileServiceFiles'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableControllerConfigAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Action returned 'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Employee] AS [Employee], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Monitor_Date] AS [Monitor_Date], 
    [Extent1].[Region] AS [Region], 
    [Extent1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Easement] AS [Easement], 
    [Extent1].[Subdivision] AS [Subdivision], 
    [Extent1].[Subdivision_Num] AS [Subdivision_Num], 
    [Extent1].[GPSLat] AS [GPSLat], 
    [Extent1].[GPSLong] AS [GPSLong], 
    [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Extent1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Extent1].[Zip_Code] AS [Zip_Code], 
    [Extent1].[Easement_Name] AS [Easement_Name], 
    [Extent1].[Acres] AS [Acres], 
    [Extent1].[Location] AS [Location], 
    [Extent1].[Conservation] AS [Conservation], 
    [Extent1].[Amendment] AS [Amendment], 
    [Extent1].[Sale_Date] AS [Sale_Date], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
    [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
    [Extent1].[Contact] AS [Contact]
    FROM [dbo].[Jobs] AS [Extent1]'', Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=404 (NotFound), Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/00b05662-9643-4e36-bbeb-7b1961ca3ee7/MobileServiceFiles, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableControllerConfigAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/00b05662-9643-4e36-bbeb-7b1961ca3ee7/MobileServiceFiles
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JobController.ExecuteAsync, Status=200 (OK)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=200 (OK), Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job?$skip=50&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true&$select=Id,Employee,Status,Monitor_Date,Region,Project_ID,Easement,Subdivision,Subdivision_Num,GPSLat,GPSLong,City,State,Zip_Code,Easement_Name,Acres,Location,Conservation,Amendment,Sale_Date,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,Version,Deleted,Contact, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JobController.Dispose
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/002cd22a-3288-4b85-8cc8-fabc78e614aa/MobileServiceFiles
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/002cd22a-3288-4b85-8cc8-fabc78e614aa/MobileServiceFiles, Message='https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/002cd22a-3288-4b85-8cc8-fabc78e614aa/MobileServiceFiles'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=404 (NotFound), Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/002cd22a-3288-4b85-8cc8-fabc78e614aa/MobileServiceFiles, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/002cd22a-3288-4b85-8cc8-fabc78e614aa/MobileServiceFiles
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/02ccf5f7-3fa1-479f-b8d9-bcd68f86ec35/MobileServiceFiles
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/02ccf5f7-3fa1-479f-b8d9-bcd68f86ec35/MobileServiceFiles, Message='https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/02ccf5f7-3fa1-479f-b8d9-bcd68f86ec35/MobileServiceFiles'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=404 (NotFound), Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/02ccf5f7-3fa1-479f-b8d9-bcd68f86ec35/MobileServiceFiles, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/02ccf5f7-3fa1-479f-b8d9-bcd68f86ec35/MobileServiceFiles
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/025407da-741a-4af3-bb72-ab22dbe1eec6/MobileServiceFiles
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/025407da-741a-4af3-bb72-ab22dbe1eec6/MobileServiceFiles, Message='https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/025407da-741a-4af3-bb72-ab22dbe1eec6/MobileServiceFiles'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=404 (NotFound), Method=GET, Url=https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/025407da-741a-4af3-bb72-ab22dbe1eec6/MobileServiceFiles, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/tables/Job/025407da-741a-4af3-bb72-ab22dbe1eec6/MobileServiceFiles
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677', Issuer: 'https://dugisfieldstaff.azurewebsites.net/'.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated sid:ed7044f07e2aad7b3844e30a8f439677 successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.
The thread 0x2030 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x23c8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: From the errors you provided, I found that errors are thrown when invoking the `GetRecordFilesAsync` method. And the (400) Bad Request is thrown at `CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists`. Please try to make sure the `containerName` is valid. Please pay attention that a container name could contain only letters, numbers and the dash(-) character and all letters in a container name need to be lowercase. For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) about the naming rules of a container name.

Comment: Bruce, The Id column in the database is set to "[Id] [nvarchar](128) DEFAULT NEWID() Not Null," and in my model it is set to "public New_Contact() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");}" I quickly reviewed the Id column in the database and the only thing I can find is that one record is lowercase, and the rest are uppercase, but all conform to being a GUID. I don't see anything that is not a Alpha or Numeric or a Dash. I will try a script to find a anything else, but is there something else it could be?

Answer (score 0):

The error “StatusMessage:The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.” is thrown by the Azure Storage library. 
The container names must be in lowercase. Can you please try your guid to be in lowercase if it helps?

Please refer to the naming guidelines: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx

Comment: I updated the tables of the database that Azure is using, and I now can't get any tables to sync. I changed the error output above to reflect the morphing of the issue.